# Hashtags work fine but not showing in browser url - Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, hashtag

I have added hashtags on my menu links (Drupal 7) and it is jumping to the correct content as needed with a smooth effect. However the browser url is not changing (http://mysite.com) as i want it to be changed with the hash (http://mysite.com/#section1, ..etc ) so users can press the back button and return to the previous (hash) page. I tried "jQuery hashchange event" and did not work. Maybe something can be done on drupal? Any advice is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a javascript on your page which blocks this:
Something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: I have double checked and did not find any :(

Comment: It sounds you have implemented a script, which is responsible for the smooth effect. Does the browser show up a hashtag... or does it not change at all?

Comment: The browser does not show up the hashtag at all but it works properly.

Comment: Maybe It is possible to find a solution if you post the name of the plugin or your scripts, which prevents the hashtag.